# Inheritance to Sub Sub Class

Tags: java, inheritance

I am working on an assignment have a question regarding subclass inheritance, actually an issue with a subclass of a subclass. I have three classes, Fruit(main class), Apple(subclass of fruit, also abstract), Macintosh(Subclass of apple). Fruit contains a series of constructor methods, Apple is abstract and contains one method, and MacIntosh contains a constructor call to the superclass(Fruit).

Fruit.java

```
public abstract class Fruit extends Object {
    // The name of the fruit
    protected String mName;
    // Number of calories
    protected int mCalories;
    // Color of the fruit
    protected Color mColor;
    // Weight of the fruit, in pounds
    protected double mWeight;

    protected Fruit() {
        this("Apple");
        // Default fruit
    }

    protected Fruit(String name) {
        this(name, 0);
    }

    protected Fruit(String name, int calories) {
        this(name, calories, null);
    }

    protected Fruit(String name, int calories, Color color) {
        this(name, calories, color, 0d);
    }

    protected Fruit(String name, int calories, Color color, double weight) {
        this.mName = name;
        this.mCalories = calories;
        this.mColor = color;
        this.mWeight = weight;
    }
```

Apple.java

```
abstract class Apple extends Fruit {    

    abstract void bite();

}
```

Macintosh.java

```
public class Macintosh extends Apple {

    public Macintosh() {
        super(Macintosh.class.getSimpleName(), 200, new Red(), 0.14d);
    }

    void bite() {
        setWeight(getWeight() - 0.01d);
    }

}
```

When I run the program I get the following error:

```
  super(Macintosh.class.getSimpleName(), 200, new Red(), 0.14d);
  ^
  required: no arguments
  found: String,int,Red,double
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error
```

I understand what the error is saying I'm just confused as to why the inheritance is not being passed down from Fruit to Apple to Macintosh. When I extend Fruit from the Macintosh class the program works, however, it seems that there can't be a class in between the two. If anyone could explain this that would be great.

Comment: What does `super(..)` do within a constructor?

Comment: I believe it sets the defaults based on the superclass constructor

Comment: What do you mean by _sets the defaults_? What is the superclass constructor in this case?

Comment: its constructing an apple called macintosh. I more so meant the constrcutor characteristics of a macinotsh apple. The constructors are in the fruit class but I understand now that these arent inherited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Constructors are not inherited, so even though Apple extends Fruit, the only way to construct an Apple is to call one of the constructors provided by Apple (in this case the default no-arg constructor). When your Macintosh extends Apple, it must use the constructor provided by Apple.

For your code you would have to at least provide the following constructor to Apple

```
Apple(String name, int calories, Color color, double weight) {
    super(name, calories, color, weight);
}
```

Comment: Okay great this is exactly what I was looking for. I didn't know those constructors were not inherited.

Comment: So in general I would need to have a similar constructor setup compared to my Fruit class?

Comment: @RichLuick Yes, you would. Also note that the call to super has to be the first thing in the constructor, but you can manipulate the arguments such as `super(name + " which is an Apple", calories, color, weight);`

Answer (score 2):

Provide a valid constructor in Apple:

```
abstract class Apple extends Fruit {  

    protected Apple (String name, int calories, Color color, double weight) {
       super(name, calories, color, weight);
    }

    abstract void bite();

}
```

Notice that constructors are not inherited.

Answer (score 1):

you call apple constructor with 4 argument but in apple class you don't have constructor for this code :

```
  super(Macintosh.class.getSimpleName(), 200, new Red(), 0.14d);
```

you need define apple constructor with four parameter like this :

```
Apple(String name, int calories, Color color, double weight) {
    super(name, calories, color, weight);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you say super in Macintosh, it refers to Apple which has no constructor. You should define a constructor in Apple that calls its super's constructor which is Fruit's

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a constructor for `Apple` with the right arguments

Answer (score 0):

you need appropriate constructor in your parent. because object create structure is starts from child class constructor, then super, then super. so you should maintain the constructor structure